# Simple example of ContactsContract API

Tags: android, contacts

Other than the brief article at android site:-

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html

I haven't seen any docs on using the new ContactsContract API. Can someone please direct me to an example/explanation of using it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [ContactManager](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ContactManager/index.html) and [SampleSyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html) samples, located in your SDK path.

Comment: it seems that devices when you work on contacts they compiled some things differently?