# Can someone explain ContactsContracts?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm relatively new to android and programming in general and I'm practicing by trying to make an app that emulates what the Contacts/People app does (show my contacts). I've spent some time doing research and I'm having trouble understanding how ContactsContract work.

I'm not understanding how to access the contacts information, for example Emails, Phone numbers and addresses. I know you can get the contact _id or lookup_key (not sure which is better) from the ContactsContract.Contacts but to get all the compiled information for that particular aggregated contact would mean that you have to go through all the raw contacts associated with it. That seems inefficient and complicated. Is there a way to access all that information from one spot for example say a "ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.(Data associated with that aggregated Contact)"?

On a side note, would it be possible to modify the data (i.e adding a new phone number or removing an email) directly into that "ContactsContract.Contacts.Data" table if it exists? I have done little to no research on adding information to contacts so this may actually be really easy and I have no clue, I just thought I'd ask while I'm here.

Comment: It gives you keys and constants that may change across APIs, so you don't have to manually code them yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Simple example of ContactsContract API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930742/simple-example-of-contactscontract-api)

Just to let you know some stack overflow users will down mark you or stop your post because you say you not done much looking etc. So be sure to have a look on the net before you ask a question hope this link helps you.

Comment: Understood. I'll make sure not ask something I haven't look into yet. It was just an after thought, hitting two bird with one stone. Thanks for the link though.